# Difference between the def and useAsDefault parameters of setGeneric

Tags: r, r-s4

In the S4 [setGeneric function documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/methods/versions/3.6.2/topics/setGeneric), the difference between the `def` and `useAsDefault` parameters is poorly explained: they seem to do the same thing, but in practice there's a confusing and poorly contextualised explanation. Could anybody provide a practical example where the two entries behave differently?

Answer (score 3):

#### Some context

For better or worse, the behaviour of `setGeneric` differs in quite subtle ways depending on its arguments.  It is possible that some of these quirks are not intentional.  The help page accessed by `?setGeneric` and even the reference book *Extending R* (Chambers, 2016) follow the Pareto principle by spelling out the most frequent use cases and only sketching out the less frequent ones, in particular not expounding about `useAsDefault` whose use is intended only for nonstandard generic functions.

S4 generic functions are designated by the formal class `genericFunction`, which has three direct subclasses: `standardGeneric`, `nonstandardGenericFunction`, and `groupGenericFunction`.  To give context to the behaviour of `setGeneric`, we should distinguish between standard and nonstandard generic functions.  (Group generic functions are defined by `setGroupGeneric`, not `setGeneric`, so we ignore them here.)

*Standard* generic functions only perform method dispatch: arguments are passed "as is" to the dispatched method, and the return value of the method is returned "as is" by the generic.  *Nonstandard* generic functions perform method dispatch while allowing for pre-processing of arguments and post-processing of return values.

Hence if we define a generic function with `setGeneric("zzz", def=)`, then in the standard case `body(zzz)` is just the call `standardGeneric("zzz")`, whereas in the nonstandard case it is a call *containing* the call `standardGeneric("zzz")`, typically of the form:

```r
{
    ## optionally do some stuff with the arguments
    val <- standardGeneric("zzz")
    ## optionally do some stuff with 'val', then return
}
```

---

To answer your question, let's restrict attention to calls to `setGeneric` of the form

```r
setGeneric("zzz", def=, useAsDefault=)
```

where `def` is a function and `useAsDefault` is either a function or missing, and let's further assume that there is no existing function `zzz`.

Then `setGeneric` behaves in one of three ways, depending on `body(def)`:

1. If `body(def)` does not contain the call `standardGeneric("zzz")`,
   then `setGeneric` constructs a standard generic function and assigns
   it to the symbol `zzz` in the calling environment.  It associates
   with `zzz` a default method (of formal class `derivedDefaultMethod`),
   which is retrieved as `zzz@default`.  The default method
   is `useAsDefault` if not missing and `def` otherwise.

   ```r
   setGeneric("zzz", def = function(x, ...) 1 + x, useAsDefault = function(x, ...) x)
   ## [1] "zzz"

   zzz
   ## standardGeneric for "zzz" defined from package ".GlobalEnv"
   ## 
   ## function (x, ...) 
   ## standardGeneric("zzz")
   ## <environment: 0x14f048860>
   ## Methods may be defined for arguments: x
   ## Use  showMethods(zzz)  for currently available ones.

   zzz@default
   ## Method Definition (Class "derivedDefaultMethod"):
   ## 
   ## function (x, ...) 
   ## x
   ## 
   ## Signatures:
   ##         x    
   ## target  "ANY"
   ## defined "ANY"

   zzz(0)
   ## [1] 0
   ```
2. If `body(def)` is precisely the call `standardGeneric("zzz")`,
   then, as in Case 1, `setGeneric` constructs and assigns to `zzz`
   a standard generic function.  However, here, the default method
   is determined entirely by `useAsDefault`.
   If `useAsDefault` is missing, then `zzz` gets no default method.

   ```r
   setGeneric("zzz", def = function(x, ...) standardGeneric("zzz"))
   ## [1] "zzz"

   zzz
   ## standardGeneric for "zzz" defined from package ".GlobalEnv"
   ## 
   ## function (x, ...) 
   ## standardGeneric("zzz")
   ## <environment: 0x112010f60>
   ## Methods may be defined for arguments: x
   ## Use  showMethods(zzz)  for currently available ones.

   zzz@default
   ## NULL

   zzz(0)
   ## Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
   ##   unable to find an inherited method for function 'zzz' for signature '"numeric"'
   ```
3. If `body(def)` is not precisely the call `standardGeneric("zzz")`,
   but does contain it, then `setGeneric` constructs and assigns to
   `zzz` a nonstandard generic function.  As in Case 2, `useAsDefault`
   specifies the default method.  However, here, the generic function
   inherits its body from `def`.

   ```r
   setGeneric("zzz", def = function(x, ...) 1 + standardGeneric("zzz"), useAsDefault = function(x, ...) x)
   ## [1] "zzz"

   zzz
   ## nonstandardGenericFunction for "zzz" defined from package ".GlobalEnv"
   ## 
   ## function (x, ...) 
   ## 1 + standardGeneric("zzz")
   ## <environment: 0x123fd5410>
   ## Methods may be defined for arguments: x
   ## Use  showMethods(zzz)  for currently available ones.

   zzz@default
   ## Method Definition (Class "derivedDefaultMethod"):
   ## 
   ## function (x, ...) 
   ## x
   ## 
   ## Signatures:
   ##         x    
   ## target  "ANY"
   ## defined "ANY"

   zzz(0)
   ## [1] 1
   ```

Comment: Beautiful answer. Case 1 definitely feels unintentional. There's no real reason for this behaviour. The authors probably wanted people to allow writing `setGeneric(name, default)` without having to specify `useAsDefault=` (since that's probably the most frequent use-case), but forgot to put in a check to prevent users from accidentally providing `useAsDefault` in addition to `def`. Though I struggle to see why they didn't simply invert the order of the arguments then: `setGeneric(name, useAsDefault, … def)`. Probably a case of hindsight being 20:20.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think Case 1 in S4 authors' opinion should be the most frequently use case. Reading through `?setGeneric` you can see that it recommended **having a default method in your mind first** then proceed with the generic function's stuff. So, `zzz <- function(x, ...) 1 + x; setGeneric("zzz")` or an alternative `setGeneric("zzz", function(x, ...) 1 + x)`. S4 automatically parse the default function to create `standardGeneric`. I think this is a good approach to ensure default method existed **and** promote the usage of `standardGeneric`.

Comment: @HieuNguyen Yes I understand that; however, this only makes sense if the user does not *also* specify `useAsDefault`. Specifying both arguments is an error (since one of them gets ignored) and should be treated as such instead of silently ignoring one argument.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I must agree with you on the silently ignore one argument part. `setGeneric("zzz", def = function(x, ...) 1 + x, useAsDefault = function(x, ...) 2 + x)` will create a `standardGeneric` through parsing of `def`, but `2 + x` is used as default method while `1 + x` is ignored completely. I think your suggestion should be a feature request to R Core!

Comment: Good thanks, but I still don't see when I should be using one or the other. To me they seem to do the same thing unless they step on each other. I could achieve the same with only def, or only setAsDefault.

Comment: @StefanoBorini That's not quite right. For example, you can't define a nonstandard generic function without specifying `def`. Anyway, in my opinion, the most transparent usage is to always supply both `def` and `useAsDefault`, using `def` to specify the behaviour of the generic function and `useAsDefault` to specify the behaviour of the default method. Only omit `useAsDefault` if you don't want a default method.